# Pythonic way to record changes inside a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a Python script that triggers the computer webcam and is able to detect movement in the video being captured using opencv.

The way it works is Python reads the very first frame of the video and stores it as a numpy array in a variable. Then, there is a while loop running in the script that basically compares the first video frame with each current frame of the video. There are around 30 frames every second being iterated in the loop. When the current frame is different than the first frame, I update a variable inside the while loop by assigning the value 1 to it. So, as the loop goes on, you may have 0, 0, 0 and then 1, 1, 1, 1 depending on whether there is motion or not. 
My purpose is to record the time when motion starts. In other words, the time when my variable changes from 0 to 1.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
start webcam
times_list=[]
motion_list=[]
while True:
    my_variable=0
    frame_difference=current_frame - first_frame
    if frame_difference > 0:
        continue
    my_variable=1
    motion_list.append(my_variable)
    #The motion_list will get big, so let's keep only the last two items to avoid memory problems
    #The last two items is all we need.
    #Check if there was a change from non-motion to motion
    if motion_list[-1]==1 and motion_list[-2]==0:
        times_list.append(datetime.datetime.now())
```

So, at the end I have a time_list with all times when motion started.

Is this a good solution or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi, it's weekend, so I have time for you :) Following our discussion yesterday, I updated my answer accordingly. You seem, through your comments, to be interested in registering only the very first instants when the motion starts and not the whole motion timelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

## First suggestion:

There are few improvements you could do, especially if, as it is often in practice (but not necessarily), you intend to run your application on [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/what-is-a-raspberry-pi/).

In total, there are  4 cases to consider about and that your program must cover them all:

1. No motion:  ⇢ ⓪ ⇢ ⓪ ⇢ ⓪ ⇢
2. Continuous motion: ⇢ ❶ ⇢ ❶ ⇢ ❶ ⇢
3. From no motion to motion: ⓪ ⇢ ❶
4. From motion to no motion:  ❶ ⇢ ⓪

The only time to register is the one described by the case 3; while during the motion (case 2), we won't care about the time.

To resolve this, I suppose , previous to the `while` loop:

- You saved  `first_frame` somewhere
- You set `my_variable` to `0`

Here is the pseudocode:

```
times_list=[]
my_variable = 0
while True:
    frame_difference = current_frame - first_frame
    # Case 1:
    if difference_frame == 0 and my_variable == 0:
        continue
    # Case 2:
    if difference_frame != 0 and my_variable == 1:
        continue
    # Case 3:
    if difference_frame != 0 and my_variable == 0:
        my_variable = 1
        # Your comments say this is the only instant you are interested in
        times_list.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    # Case 4:
    if difference_frame == 0 and my_variable == 1:
        my_variable = 0
```

**Notes:**

1. For the sake of performance, it is better to test  cases 1 and 2 before the rest as, in practice, they occur more frequently than the two other cases. So by running continue you avoid wasting time in checking cases 3 and 4 which are less frequent.
2. We got rid of `motion_list` and not need to allocate a memory for this list anymore because `my_variable` plays the role of a flag and it satisfies  your need when by re-setting its value to `0` or `1` in the last two cases.

## Second suggestion:

If you are not doing this application as a university project but for more practical/commercial reasons, you may think of this improvement: as reading frames from camera is an I/O bound task, you may be interested in  [increasing webcam FPS](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) (and more probably in [increasing Raspberry Pi FPS](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/28/increasing-raspberry-pi-fps-with-python-and-opencv/))

Comment: So, in your code, if the first frame is the same with the current frame, the while loop will repeat above `continue` without executing `now()`.  If the current frame is different to the first frame, `now()` will be executed and the while loop will iterate again and if the next current frame is still different to the first frame, another timestamp will be recorded with `now()`. 
That means, your code will record a timestamp at each frame that has motion in it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Exactly. But I want to make your conclusion (last phrase) clearer: what defines the instant of the motion? The answer is: it is the moment where you get a frame (`current_frame`) different from your very first one.

Comment: Actually, inside the while loop I am calculating a frame difference using an `absdiff()` method and then applying a `findCountours()` method that detects the contours of the difference frame. Then again inside the while loop, I have a for loop that iterates through the contours and checks whether the countour area is less than a certain minimum given area and continues the operation if the area is less than the minimum area.

Comment: Ok. If I understood you well, you compare always `current_frame` to the **same** first frame,  right? @A.S

Comment: Excactly always to the same first frame which is the first frame captured when the webcam starts.

Comment: That is the assumption on which I based my solution. So we are on the same wave (if I may say so) and the algorithm I suggested does exactly what you are looking for because each frame that is different from your very first frame reflects a motion; thus you save the instant (time) where this frame appears. The list of instants you get finally will simply reflect the motion timeline. @A.S

Comment: But your solution will give me a timestamp for each frame that is different from the first frame, right? 
So, based on your solution if an object passes in front of the camera for one second, there may be around 30 timestamps stored there because the camera captures 30 frames in one second. 

That's not what I want. I want to store only the timestamp when the object entered the view. Maybe I can find a way just keep only the first timestamp from the list.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your final goal. Your comment is clearer. I will update my answer in the few coming hours @A.S

Comment: The updated version of the answer makes sense! Thanks for your time!